# Append 0.00 € to shipping label when cost is zero in Woocommerce order notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

I have a problem in WooCommerce when the shipment is 0.00 euros from a certain amount.The question is that the cart page does not appear 0.00 euros or free.

This is solved by entering this code in the php functions file. I saw it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655887/how-to-show-zero-rate-value-of-shipping-class-in-cart-page-woocommerce).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'add_free_shipping_label', 10, 2 );
function add_free_shipping_label( $label, $method ) {
    if ( $method->cost == 0 ) {
        $label = 'Free shipping'; //not quite elegant hard coded string
    }
    return $label;
}
```

There is also another option if you want 0.00 Euros to appear. [I discovered it in the following article](https://jeroensormani.com/add-free-shipping-label/).

```
function my_custom_show_price_with_free_shipping( $label, $method ) {

    $label = $method->get_label();

    if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
        $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
        if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
            $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
        }
    } else {
        $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
        if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! wc_prices_include_tax() ) {
            $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
        }
    }

    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'my_custom_show_price_with_free_shipping', 10, 2 );
```

The question is that in the notifications that the client receives via e-mail of his purchase and invoices in the sending part he does not put anything. As much as I have investigated, I have not found anything.

I have searched but I have not found anything. Can you help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For orders, email notifications *(and maybe PDF)*, you will use something like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_method', 'custom_order_shipping_method_labels', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_shipping_method_labels( $labels, $order ) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ( $order->get_items('shipping') as $item ) {
        $total += $item->get_total();
    }
    if( $total == 0 ){
        $labels .= ' ' . wc_price( 0 );
    }
    return $labels;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> Remember that an order can have multiple shipping methods in some cases...

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly. Thanks once again.